# ModelBinders vs Sitecore Debug mode

Tags: performance-optimization, performance, performance-profiling, debug

We used `ModelBinders.Binders` on our project to make resolving of controller action parameters easier and make code more testable.

```
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(SomeType)] = new SomeTypeModelBinder();
```

Model binder resolves object:

```
public class SomeTypeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
       var someTypeResolver = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISomeTypeResolver>();
       return someTypeResolver.GetCurrentSomeType();
    }
}
```

Then it becomes easy to use this type as model in our controllers:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeType someType)
{
    return View(someType);
}
```

The problem is that it becomes hard to measure performance of action using Sitecore Debug. **It looks like binding of action parameter in this way causes that it is not summed up to time of rendering controller action**(this assumptions is done, because time of rendering is too small):

> Finished rendering "Controller: SomeController. Action: SomeAction".  26.62 ms

The questions are:

- Does Sitecore Debug mode take into account time that is spent on
  execution of model binders?
- If not, then how to force Sitecore Debug
  mode to start add this time to total time of execution(and remain code testable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked how Sitecore timers for debug mode are implemented, and modify my code:

```
public class SomeTypeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
       Tracer.Info("Starting BindModel for SomeType");
       Tracer.Indent++;
       Profiler.StartOperation("BindModel for SomeType.");
       var someTypeResolver = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISomeTypeResolver>();
       var object = someTypeResolver.GetCurrentSomeType();
       Profiler.EndOperation("BindModel for SomeType.");
       return object;
    }
}
```

That is not exact thing that I wanted, but adds more information in debug mode about timings.